# unable to implement audit log using triggers in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I tried to implement an audit log as defined in the following URL : https://eager.io/blog/audit-postgres/.

When I tried to run the FUNCTION `audit.if_modified_func()`, the function is not executed and an error appears.
It says ERROR:

```
type "hstore" is only a shell.  LINE 6:     h_old hstore;
```

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Is the error when you really tried to run the function, or when you tried to create the function?  Did you follow the previous steps of creating the hstore extension and the logged_actions table?

Comment: yes i created the logged_actions table and created hstore extension